# (+) operator for join , but strange

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I have this Oracle code, which I need to convert to SQL Server:

```
FROM 
    dbo.userid t,
    dbo.securityuser us,
    dbo.dbaudit dba
WHERE 
    t.userid = us.userid
    t.userid = dba.keyvalue(+)
```

I have a problem with

```
t.userid = dba.keyvalue(+)
```

Here the plus operator is after the column and the left joins are done using

```
table1.col(+) = table2.col
```

Please help me to understand what actually it is doing.

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 3):

I think you want:

```
FROM dbo.userid t JOIN
     dbo.securityuser us
     ON  t.userid = us.userid LEFT JOIN
     dbo.dbaudit dba
     ON t.userid = dba.keyvalue
```